# Create text cutout in image blurred with backdrop-filter

Tags: css

How can I replicate this effect:

[image: this effect]

in CSS? I tried making block with backdrop-filter in it, but can't find any solution to "un-blur" text inside. GitHub link inside of image is non-mandatory in replication.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.